# Quantum algorithm of graphs: How to create superposition of paths?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing

Let us allow path to have same vertexes in it. (defining)

So suppose we have a graph of $N$ vertexes and we want to separate it into some superposition of paths that have $N$ vertexes (so if the number of vertexes is $N$, there would be like $N^N$ paths.)

Is this possible? If it is, how can this be done?

Comment: Create a uniform superposition over sufficiently many bits, and then use a classical algorithm to treat each outcome as the description of a path.

Comment: Some links that might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_quantum_walk ; http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209131 ; http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v102/i18/e180501 ; http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3782 and the references therein.